# Facebook Open Graph - Can "og.likes" action be assigned with "product" type?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

The following iOS code ("object" type with "og.likes" action) works just fine:

```
let properties = [
    "og:type": "object",
    "og:title": "Test Product",
    "og:description": "Product description"
]

let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)

let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
action.actionType = "og.likes"
action.setObject(object, forKey: "object")

let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
content.action = action
content.previewPropertyName = "object"

FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

However, I prefer using "product" type rather than the generic "object" type. The following code is the same as the above one only replacing "object" with "product" (so this time trying to post a story about "product" type with "og.likes" action)

```
let properties = [
    "og:type": "product",
    "og:title": "Test Product",
    "og:description": "Product description"
]

let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)

let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
action.actionType = "og.likes"
action.setObject(object, forKey: "product")

let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
content.action = action
content.previewPropertyName = "product"

FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

This code generated the following error:

> Action Requires At Least One Reference: The action you’re trying to
>   publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects.
>   At least one of the following properties must be specified: object.

Any idea why?

Comment: The parameter name is always `object`.

Comment: When I pass "books.book" instead of "object" and "books.read" instead of "og.likes" everything is working fine as well. So clearly, you don't have to always pass "object" as you suggested. Could it be related to special FB permissions that are required?

Comment: “Always” was referring to the og.likes action here ... // Now, try and publish your `books.read` action not using a parameter named `books.book`, but `hrgstfl` instead ... What, doesn’t work? Well that’s because instead of supplying a parameter under the _expected_ name, you supplied one of your own choosing. Conclusion, we need to use the parameter name that the documentation says we must use, and not something else. Now, do the same thing with your og.likes action - use the parameter name `object`, and not something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for my misunderstanding! Can you kindly explain what action can I use for parameter named "product"? I am a total newbie in FB open graph, so I'm sorry if question sound stupid...

Comment: You are confusing API call parameters with the type of your Open Graph object (a product is still an Open Graph object - just one of a more specific type than the general “object”). Take your first code, and change the `og:type`, and _nothing else_.

Comment: Do you mean to change only `"og:type": "object"` to `"og:type": "product"` and leave the rest as is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142514/discussion-between-joshua-and-cbroe).

Comment: Issue resolved?